# Weird behaviour of a if statement in glsl with three.js

Tags: javascript, glsl, three.js

I have a problem with an if statement in my shader :
Here is my shader and my code :[code & shader](http://pastebin.com/6xfYe4kF)

I have several WebglRenderTarget :

In target_color  I put my scene to an arbitrary color .
I also have a WebglRenderTarget target_position (see the image).
The final shader is problem_shader it uses the two textures target_color and target_position, you can see in the image what I expect and what I get.

[IMAGE](http://postimage.org/image/r2xg29rfp/)

So the line in my shader that have a strange behaviour is

```
"if(z_min<0.6){if(FOCUS.a<0.3){col=RED;}else{col=WHITE;}}else{col=GREEN;};",
```

it shoud have the same behaviour that (expected result in the image):

```
"if(z_min<0.6){col=WHITE;}else{col=GREEN;}",
```

What is the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you are drawing multiple times with a different FOCUS/z_min?

Comment: I wonder if trying to reproduce this on the glslsandbox may be helpful. http://glsl.heroku.com/

Comment: i have 3 shaders and in this sandbox i can write only one no ?